# Intepretation of $dC_1=-\theta(dT_1+\frac{dT_2}{1+r})=0\Longleftrightarrow dT_1=-\frac{dT_2}{1+r}$?

Tags: macroeconomics

We are studying the Ricardian equivalence in a macro course and we are asked to show that a tax cut today will be matched by a tax hike tomorrow. I believe the above is supposed to be the solution, however I do not quite understand the total differential and even less so the notation. I have three questions:

1. How exactly do I take the total derivative of $C_1=\theta(V_1+Y^L_1-T_1+\frac{Y^L_2-T_2}{1+r})$ with respect to $T_1$ and $T_2$?
2. How would I then get to $dC_1=-\theta(dT_1+\frac{dT_2}{1+r})$?
3. What is the interpretation of $dT_1$ and $dT_2$? Specifically, what is the interpretation of $dT_1=-\frac{dT_2}{1+r}$?

Comment: What's $V_1$ and $Y_1^L$ , as in what's their interpretation? Are these constants or they can change if tax changes? What I can interpret is they are fixed or given.

Comment: $V_1$ is initial wealth in period 1 and $Y^L_1$ is income in period 1. They do not change with $T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Basic intro to total differentiation**

Suppose we have a function $$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n).$$ The total derivative is given by $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}dx_1+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}dx_2+\ldots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}dx_n,$$
where the $\partial$ terms are partial derivatives and the $dx$ terms are so-called "differentials".

Conceptually, what is going on is the following: we ask "if I change every variable $x_i$ by a *small* amount $dx_i$, what is the effect on the overall value of $f$?"

To answer this question, we can think about the variables one-by-one. Start with $x_1$. A unit increase in $x_1$ causes $f$ to change by $\partial f/\partial x_1$. We are making a small $dx_1$ unit change in $x_1$. Thus, the total change in $f$ due to the change in $x_1$ is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}dx_1$. At the same time, we change $x_2$ by $dx_2$, resulting in a $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}dx_2$ unit change in $f$ and so on.

If you want to read more on the topic, I'd recommend the relevant chapter of "Fundamental Methods of Mathematical Economics" by Alpha Chiang.

---

**Aside on why this might be useful (can be skipped without loss)**

Let's look at an example of how this could be useful. Suppose we have a game where players $i=1,2$ each choose an action $x_i$. Player $i$'s payoff is

$$u_i=f(x_i,a)+g(x_i,x_j,a)$$

where $a$ is a parameter and $x_j$ is the other player's action. Thus, a player's best action is given by the first-order condition

$$f_1(x_i,a)+g_1(x_i,x_j,a)=0$$
where $f_i$ means the partial derivative of $f$ wrt its $i^{th}$ argument.

It is hard to know how a change in the parameter $a$ will affect $i$'s choice of $x_i$ because the change in $a$ will affect $x_i$ not only directly, but also by changing $x_j$. When all of these changes have settled back to equilibrium, what happens? It seems like we can't go any further because we need to know the functional form of $f$ and $g$ to be able to explicitly solve for $x_i$ and see how they depend on each other and on $a$.

But total differentiation can help us understand the properties of the solution here. Let's totally differentiate the first order condition, allowing all of $x_i$, $x_j$, and $a$ to change at once (I omit the arguments of the functions for brevity):

$$[f_{11}+g_{11}]dx_i+g_{12}dx_j+[f_{12}+g_{13}]da=0.$$

Now I can solve for $\frac{dx_i}{da}$:

$$\frac{dx_i}{da}=-\frac{f_{12}+g_{13}}{f_{11}+g_{11}}.$$
So long as I know something about the individual properties of $f$ and $g$, I can use this equation to tell me what the sign of $fx_i/da$ will be!

---

**Coming back to your example**

For notational convenience, I give your function a name ($f$):

$$f(C_1,T_1,T_2)\equiv\theta(V_1+Y^L_1-T_1+\frac{Y^L_2-T_2}{1+r})-C_1=0,$$

we apply the basic rules of total differentiation:

$$f_1 dC_1+f_2dT_1+f_3dT_2=0.$$

We compute $f_1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial C_1}=-1$,$f_2=\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_1}=-\theta$, $f_3=\frac{\partial f}{\partial T_2}=-\theta\frac{1}{1+r}$. This therefore gives $$dC_1=-\theta\left(dT_1+\frac{dT_2}{1+r}\right).$$

In words, this equation tells us that the change in $C_1$ must be equal to $-\theta\left(dT_1+\frac{dT_2}{1+r}\right)$, where $dT_1$ and $dT_2$ are the changes in $T_1$ and $T_2$. Thus, if we want to say that $C_1$ doesn't change then it must be that $dT_1=-\frac{dT_2}{1+r}$ so that the changes in $T_1$ and $T_2$ 'cancel-out'.